# splitting data into multiple tables in hive

Tags: hive

I have a data which contains 100 million rows.I need to split it into tables of 10 million each.How could this be done in hive.

The effective sql query is:

```
 select * from Customers where rownum>0 and rownum<=1000000  
 select * from Customers where rownum>1000000 and rownum<=2000000
```

and so on..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hive has `ROW_NUMBER` as an [analytics function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) if you're using a recent version.

Otherwise, you could do something like:

```
from (select Customers.*, rand() as r from Customers) t
insert overwrite table Customers_sample1 select * where r < 0.1
insert overwrite table Customers_sample2 select * where r >=0.1 and r < 0.2
insert overwrite table Customers_sample3 select * where r >=0.2 and r < 0.3
...
```